# Placing elements of one list according to another list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists `Cb_max1` and `J1`. I want to place the elements of `Cb_max1` according to indices in `J1`.

But, I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
Cb_max1 = [[0.0009847628716281426, 0.0009847628716281426, 0.0009800221856714917]]
J1=[[1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]]

for i in range(0,len(J1[0])):
    Cb_max1=Cb_max1[0][J1[0][i]]
    print(Cb_max1)
```

The error is :

```
in <module>
    Cb_max1=Cb_max1[0][J1[0][i]]

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

The expected output is :

```
[[0.0009847628716281426, 0.0009847628716281426, 0, 0, 0, 0.0009800221856714917, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cb_max1 = [[0.0009847628716281426, 0.0009847628716281426, 0.0009800221856714917]]
J1=[[1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]]

k=[x for x in J1[0] if x!=0]   #here creating a list with non zero values
print(k)
#[1, 4, 9]

d=dict(zip(k,Cb_max1[0]))
print(d)   #here creating a dictionary mapping values with Cb_max1
#{1: 0.0009847628716281426, 4: 0.0009847628716281426, 9: 0.0009800221856714917}


[[d[x] if x in d else x for x in J1[0]]] 
#[[0.0009847628716281426, 0.0009847628716281426, 0, 0, 0, 0.0009800221856714917, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you are trying to do: if J1 is your index array, then 4 and 9 would result in an indexOutOfBoundError. The problem with your code is that you're replacing Cb_max1 by a float at the first iteration of the loop, resulting into an error at the 2nd iteration.
If as I understood J1 is your index array(i.e. contains number from `0` to `len(Cb_max1)-1)`, then the following should work:

```
import numpy as np
np.asarray(Cb_max1[0])[J1[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, the 2nd index of `Cb_max1` (i.e., `J1[0][i]`) will returns values 4 and 9, they are out of `Cb_max1` range of index.

The following code work.

```
Cb_max1 = [[0.0009847628716281426, 0.0009847628716281426, 0.0009800221856714917]]
J1=[[1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]]

# Initialize result list
result = [0] * len(J1[0])

count = 0
for J1_idx, val in enumerate(J1[0]):
    if val != 0:
        result[J1_idx] = Cb_max1[0][count]
        count += 1
        
print([result])
```

In which, I use `count` as the index to access `Cb_max1` list within the `for` loop.